# Where to Start for Building a Product Catalog

Tags: catalog

I've been asked to develop a product catalog for our company.  We have maybe 20 products, but I'm not sure where to start.

I have some PHP experience and Wordpress CMS experience.  I was hoping for an existing framework or solution so I wouldn't have to start from scratch.  Anyone have any ideas?

I'm not looking for an ecommerce site as we are NOT selling anything through the site.  Its just a showcase.

Answer (score 2):

Especially if you don't ever want to sell: Don't use a framework. Use Wordpress! Create a site for every product, and link them appropriately. Use a theme that allows you to group sites.

This way you work with a CMS you are familiar with, you have the advantage of all the Wordpress goodies (permalinks come to mind), and you don't have to code much at all.

Comment: Thank you martin for the suggestion.  I'm gonna keep this open for a few more days to see what others suggest.  Thank you again -shai

Answer (score 0):

Opencart is a great solution can be easy moded as product catalog
Check their forums